# Acts-as-taggable-on - Trouble putting all of the pieces together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm having a heck of a time getting [acts-as-taggable-on working](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). I am new to Ruby/RoR, and I feel that sometimes these plugins (although great) lack the very basic implementation instructions for people who aren't used to working in Rails.

I have a simple Content model that I want to be able to add tags to. When I save the form, nothing happens. I try to output the tags and nothing is showing (I've gone into rails console, nothing). Do I need an additional attribute (column) on my Content model (table)? I have a feeling I'm missing something very basic.

Content model:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_taggable
    # I've also tried acts_as_taggable :tags
end
```

In my form partial:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label 'Tags' %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
</p>
```

In my show.html.erb:

```
<p>
    <strong>Tags</strong>: 
    <% for tag in @content.tags %> 
        <%= link_to tag.name, contents_path(:view =>'tag', :tag => tag.name) %>
    <% end %>
</p>
```

I'm hoping someone can get me pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

---

**edit**

[Here's a link to the logs](http://pastie.org/1403704), you can see it's saving the tag_list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the problem. After posting a [link to the logs](http://pastie.org/1403704) I noticed this:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tag_list
```

I needed to add :tag_list to attr_accessible:

```
attr_accessible :name, :desc, :tag_list
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been banging my head for the last 4 hours!

Comment: Me as well, several hours of head banging.